# Run browser as if from different location

Tags: browser

occasionally when im trying to visit various websites on the web i get the error "this page is not available from your location" or "this video is not available from your location"

I know theres ways of running programs as a different time so is there a way to run a program from a "virtual" location?

Answer (score 0):

Those websites use your ip for determining your location, use proxy server for specific region  where you can use website. But this question should be on superuser.com